# Is GraphObject can be used with ShareDiaog in android

Tags: android, ios, facebook-graph-api

I've used GraphObject to share user story here is my object.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
                params.putString("reward", permaLink);
                params.putBoolean("fb:explicitly_shared", true);

                GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(
                        MainActivity.getInstance().mSimpleFacebook.getAccessToken(),
                        "me/rewardster:redeem",
                        params,
                        HttpMethod.POST,
                        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                                Log.i(TAG, graphResponse.toString());
                            }
                        }
                );

                request.executeAsync();
```

It works fine, is it possible for me to share it via ShareDialog, so user can add text to it or tag someone from friend list. etc? 
If my current code is not good with share dialog please help me translating my graph object to some other model which is compatible with share dialog.

Its possible in IOS by the way.

There must be some way out of it in android as well.

```
FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction alloc] init];
        action.actionType = @"rewardster:redeem";
        [action setString:rewardObj.fbStoryLink forKey:@"reward"];


        FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *content = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent alloc] init];
        content.action = action;
        content.previewPropertyName = @"reward";



        [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
                                     withContent:content
                                        delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

NO, if you use share dialog you cant customize much[there is few flexibilty], hence to customize the post as a story and add custom fields and to modify the post we use graph stories check out the link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph. Both allows you to share but the post will look different. 
to create a custom graph story refer this link
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/custom
**To achieve those custom things that you have asked you need to use graph-api only**

Comment: Thanks for responding, I think you missed some link in your post. 
... hence to customize the post as a story and add custom fields and to modify the post we use "this"...
Please share the link.

Comment: are you doing it for ios android or web

Comment: I am doing it for android and IOS, ios works fine with Graph object and share dialog (code shown in my question). But unable to figure it out for android.